# Running jdk 8 in docker suddenly broken on arch linux with "unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory"

Tags: linux, java, arch-linux, docker

I am trying to restart my docker containers after upgrading my system yesterday. I am running an `sbt` (scala build tool) container. Unfortunately, it stopped working with the following error

```
library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 46:    76 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$@"
```

I then found out that any java application I have dockerized stopped working. So I tried running a simple tomcat. The result is below (clipped at the bottom because it's hundreds of lines of `[Too many errors, abort]`

```
docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.0                                                                                                                                             
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /docker-java-home/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb6b7b3e532, pid=1, tid=140422755079936
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_181-b01) (build 1.7.0_181-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.181-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.14
# Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie), package 7u181-2.6.14-1~deb8u1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x36532]  abort+0x232
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/local/tomcat/core or core.1
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/tomcat/hs_err_pid1.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I found this post just now which seems to be a trace that someone else has suffered similar issues in the recent arch release

https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/155#issuecomment-471728441

Answer (score 15):

Running the tomcat works when changing the ulimit on the container with

```
docker run -it --ulimit nofile=122880:122880 -m 3G --rm tomcat:8.0
```

I found out (because my `/etc` folder is managed with a git repo) that there was a line change in

```
systemd/system.conf 
  55│ #DefaultLimitNOFILE=1024:524288
```

It seems that systemd changed the DefaultLimitNOFile and this triggers my issues.

[This article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-apply-resource-limits-via-limits-conf-for-a-docker-container/) describes how to set the ulimit for docker. That however didn't cut it for me. I had to set

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --default-ulimit nofile=65536:65536 -H fd://
```

inside of `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` Note the `--default-ulimit` flag which applies to each call of `docker`.

Comment: Thank you!
For those who don't have any docker overrides on their install yet, follow this excellent walkthrough on updating this https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/299606

Answer (score 0):

Login to the Docker container using the command `docker exec -it imagename bash` and input the command `ulimit -n 65536`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).